# HiddenField Lost on postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

We have an asp.net web page with a Hidden control on it:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="inputValue" />
```

Which holds information entered by a user for use later. The page also has this in the head section of the web page to refresh the page every 20 seconds:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
```

This is done to refresh the page with new information from a database.

Now if I use in my code behind the inputValue.Value i can correctly get the value entered by a person. However if the page refreshes before I need to get this value then inputValue.Value will be empty.

So my question is how can I make sure that inputValue.Value will have the informaton saved to it after the page refreshes? Javascript is out of the question as some of the devices accessing this page can not run javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refresh will simply reload the URL, so you will have to store state in the querystring

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, in doing some research that is what I was coming to find out. Since I'm not passing data from one page to the next, would a session variable work?

And tested with the session variable and works great.